# Order Statistics Strict Inequality

Tags: probability-theory

I am currently going over order statistics, and I have the following doubt. The book from which I'm studying says:

*Let $F$ be a continuous univariate distribution function with density function $f$, and consider $X_1,...,X_n \xrightarrow{iid} F$. $[...]$ The collection of order statistics consists of the same values as the original sample of $X$s, with the additional constraint that they are ordered from smallest to largest:
\begin{equation*}
X_{(1)} < X_{(2)} < \cdots < X_{(n)}
\end{equation*}*

Now, most of what's written makes sense to me, but I cannot wrap my head around the use of strict inequality $<$ instead of weak inequality $\leq$. The second would seem the logic choice to me, since each $X_i$ is independently drawn from the same population $F$! What am I missing?

I'm aware it's probably a very basic question, so forgive my ignorance if that's the case!

Comment: It doesn't really matter much because when we draw from a continuous distribution as here, you can show that the probability of having any ties is $0$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth you're right, exactly what I was looking for, how stupid of me! If you add this as an answer, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter because the probability of having any ties is $0$ when the distribution is continuous.